# How to access computer's local host on Android phone?

Tags: android, google-app-engine, servlets, android-studio

I'm currently using Android Studio to prototype an Android application. I'm trying to use the Google App Engine Servlet Module to write a prototype backend for my app. I can run the dev server and access the page via localhost:8080. However, I cannot access this address on my physical android phone over the same wifi connection.

I understand that I cannot use the term localhost within the Android's web browser because that does not refer to the computer's instance of localhost. I tried looking up my computer's ipv4 address and using the "ipaddress:8080" to access the page on the phone, but that does not seem to work either for the Servlet Module within Android Studio.

I have an older server application running on Apache Tomcat within Eclipse. When I run that, I am able to utilize the "ipaddress:8080" method to access the page on my android device.

Any ideas as to why this works while the Android Studio Google App Engine Servlet Module dev server fails? Any suggestions as how to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized that the server did not bind to my IP address. I changed configuration settings within Android Studio for my server to use http address "0.0.0.0". It now works.

Answer (score 1):

You can access the localhost in the following way : 10.0.2.2:8080

Comment: That is true for android emulators but not for physical devices.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was receiving null for list request after deploying backend (running on Android device). For some reason backend received requests and didn't respond. The fix for me was to re-deploy and create new project, syncing with my android project front-end code. Then as a result my front end was connected to the back-end exactly as described here: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gradle-appengine-templates/tree/master/HelloEndpoints step 2.3, and two additional fields were generated in my JSON: "kind" and "etag"